# Datasource setting saved in properties file not loaded until after reboot

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

My application source its Datasource settings from a properties file. When I start Tomcat I load the properties file, make changes to it depending on the enviroment Tomcat is running, typically UAT or Production - and base on this pass the appropriate Setting values require for Database connection.

My problem is, when the properties file is updated at bootstrap for the first time with the new connection values, on tomcat - Spring sessionFactory do not seem to acquire the current updated values, and therefore end up with Database connection exception. But when I restart Tomcat - sessionFactory now have access to the updated values.

My question is - do anyone know why sessionFactory only works with the previous values as oppose to the updated settings values?

Comment: I can understand the rationale of this need in development environment. But do you in production environment also really change the datasource settings daily or so?

Comment: No! doesnt change at all - once at change release

Comment: Are you actually changing your datasource properties? Or are you using something sensible like PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Comment: PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is used by Spring sessionFactory to locate the datasource attributes from the properties file - the only issue is, the properties file was updated at bootstrap and therefore expected Spring session factory to use the updated values. Like I said this has been tested on Tomcat7 and it works like a charm.

Comment: Could it be Tomcat6 startup thread issue?

Comment: Sorry chaps is my bad! been a bit stupid to say it works on tomcat7 and not 6. I have realise the UAT server runs tomcat7 and Production runs tomcat6 - and yet they both have the same issue. The reason why it worked on the UAT tomcat7 is because, the correct datasource values where already in the properties file - therefore at first load spring hibernate session factory automatically have access to the values.

Comment: But if I pass wrong value prior to deploy and update at startup, expecting the hibernate session factory to find the updated values, it doesn't and therefore ends up with connection exception unless restart tomcat.

Comment: Thorough investigation has revealed that the updated version of the properties file is not reloaded or refreshed and hence the old values. Do anyone knows how to refresh the properties file programmatically to load the new values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used Maven Filter to replace profile properties at build time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to restart tomcat, because connection creates in spring context.
Spring context creates on start up. When you change something in property file, actually it doesn't influence on spring context, because it is already created.